# I'm making a table Rounded Edges - Noob question

Tags: objects

[image]

So I used a cylinder to make the table head but I've noted the irl table edges aren't just flat they tend to be a tad rounded I just need to know how to make the edges of this table rounded, I've tried smoothing the vertices and extruding them doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: have you tried bevel? select the edge, ctrl b, and change the amount of edges on the bottom of the T panel

Comment: I tried bevel and this happened https://i.imgrpost.com/imgr/2018/11/12/sticks.png

Comment: you must switch to edge mode, select the top circle edge and the bottom circle edge and ctrl B

Answer (score 2):

- In the 3D view, switch to *Edge Select* mode.
- Select both top and bottom circles.
- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> to create a bevel, change the parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel of the 3D view (<kbd>T</kbd>).
- Add a *Smooth Shading* and a *Subsurf* modifier.

[image]